New employee with very severe dandruff
So I just hired a guy, and it turns out he has very severe dandruff. By the end of the day his seat looks like some kids ate a bag of chips there. Also his desk, and also the whole keyboard and mouse.
Now this is a problem because we share desks, and the next day someone else might sit there. Yes, we have cleaners, but they don't vacuum the keyboard and they don't thoroughly clean the chairs. I have asked him once politely and on a normal tone, as part of the normal conversation, to clean the seat please - he lazily swatted off 70% of the stuff with his hands.
Dandruff is also a problem because this heavily hinders him in socializing and getting to know his colleagues.
There are performance issues too, and he is still on probation, but I think getting rid of the dandruff would help him with colleagues and help him to be more accepted and perceived better. This is just how the world works (Halo-effect is real.)
Am I just inviting trouble (lawsuits mainly, though not very common in Central Europe where we live) if I even mention his dandruff?
Anyone have any similar experience?

Maybe not a legal issue for mentioning dandruff, but even in the US firing someone for a medical issue is likely going to get you in trouble.

I would never fire him for dandruff - I'll clarify that in an edit. I'm concerned if I should even mention this, since there are more serious issues currently.

@Eee Wow! I didn't make fun of him. How/why did you read that into my post? His performance, I can handle, I don't  need advice on that from the internetz. Severe personal hygiene issue is unknown territory for me, so I turned to Stack Exchange for advice. If anything, this should prove that I know my limits and turn to others for advice. Why does this trigger ridicule and toxicity from you?

Just fire the guy or put him on a performance plan (very aggressive).   Don't mention dandruff.   He is already having performance issues.    You bringing up the dandruff is going to look like that is the focus and then he can claim some sort of medical issue.   I would never fire anyone for having dandruff and there is no easy way to talk about it but having a list of performance issues for a new starter, I would just part ways.

If he's falling asleep and underperforming before passing probation, that's not a great sign. You probably don't even need a PIP since that's a duplicate of what probation is. Sit down and list all the reasons why you want to keep him based on observed performance. What they did during the interview is no longer relevant.

@Nelson - 100% agree but I do suggest an aggressive PIP.    I have turned around 20-25% of soon to be fired by scaring the bejesus out of them.    I ran a helpdesk and I can't tell you how many good employees I had that were beyond awful their first few weeks.   If I wasted 4-5 weeks interviewing, hiring, and onboarding... I want at least a hail mary attempt before it ends.

I think for younger workers I would try scaring them straight. In this specific scenario though, I personally wouldn't bother with a 70 yo worker.

@Nelson - That's what 23 year old me would think.   30 year old me says... well even if I have a 50% chance less to turn around the 70 year old worker... Well the 25 year old I replace him with will last 1 year maybe 2 if I am lucky...   this will probably be this guy's last job.

Regardless - He knows that he has serious dandruff.
